# form alter user login drupal 6

Tags: forms

I have added this:

```
    function ahml_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $form['my_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => t('Example link'),
        '#href' => 'login'
      );
    }
```

into a custom module and instead of a link in the output I have two text boxes: one reads 
"example link title", the other "example link url".

Do I have this wrong of is there just something else in the system causing this to happen?

Comment: can we see the whole function?

Comment: are you looking to output a link, or a link field?

Comment: a link to sign up page. i edited and added whole function

Comment: what exactly you need to do?

Comment: i want to add a link to the register page into the login block but all this does is add two textareas. i have tried this before with success in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to write the function as follow:

```
function ahml_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //for register page
  if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
    $form['my_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#value' => l('Login page', 'user/login'),
    );
  }
  //for login page
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['my_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#value' => l('Register link', 'user/register'),
    );
  }
}
```

For additional details, check Drupal 6 [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#markup)

Comment: worked perfectly, will definitely remember this. Still dont understand why it's different from drupal 7 though.

Comment: glad it worked for you. Drupal 7 has additional types and built in libraries which is not part of Drupal 6